# Carregar array com os dados do Parse

Tags: swift, parse

Estou com um problema de cache no meu aplicativo, porque quando entro dentro de um post ele busca todos os comentários referente ao mesmo e popula o `array`, porém, quando saio do mesmo e entro em outro, o `array` ainda não foi populado com os novo comentários dando uma aparência de *delay*.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre pois você não carregou novamente quando entrou no novo post, dê um "refresh" a cada vez que carregar uma tela, para assim atualizar os dados. Isso não é um problema de cache.

Se estiver usando uma tableView:

***tableView.reloadData()***

Se estiver usando uma ViewController:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170142/using-pull-to-refresh-in-view-controller-in-swift

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na viewwillappear eu dou um reload data, o meu problema é que ele puxa os dados do array do post anterior porque o método de busca no servidor é assíncrono.